# how to get rid of the warning "this pattern-matching is not exhaustive..."?

Tags: function, ocaml, warnings

I wrote the following function in OCaml that takes a nested Pair and returns a Pair(a,b) so that a is a nested Pair of all the odd elements and b is a nested Pair with all the even elements:

```
let rec split_var_val xs =
  match xs with
  | Nil -> Pair(Nil,Nil)
  | Pair(Pair(x, Pair(y, Nil)), tail) ->
      let Pair(a,b) = split_var_val tail in
      Pair(Pair(x,a),Pair(y,b)) 
  | _ -> raise X_no_match ;;
```

the function works well but I am getting the following **warning**:

```
this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(Nil|Bool _|Number _|Char _|String _|Symbol _)
```

how can I fix the function to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is produced by this expression:

```
let Pair(a,b) = split_var_val tail in
```

which assumes that `split_var_val` is always returning a value constructed with the `Pair` constructor, which is a fair assumption if we will look into the implementation (modulo the all-matching case that raises an exception).

If you would like to make this assumption you can either tell the compiler to hush, e.g.,

```
let Pair(a,b) = split_var_val tail [@@warning "-P"] in
```

or you can actually make the pattern match exhaustive, by matching on all cases,

```
let (a,b) = match split_var_val tail with
  | Pair (a,b) -> (a,b)
  | _ -> assert false in (* or something less generic *)
```

A better solution would be to rework your function and make it return a pair without wrapping it into the Pair constructor. (Basically, wrapping it with `Pair` is the same as premature upcasting), e.g.

```
let rec split_var_val xs =
  match xs with
  | Nil -> (Nil,Nil)
  | Pair(Pair(x, Pair(y, Nil)), tail) ->
      let (a,b) = split_var_val tail in
      (Pair(x,a),Pair(y,b)) 
  | _ -> raise X_no_match
```

and then, in the other places where you were using `split_var_val xs` you will just need to wrap it back as `let x,y = split_var_val xs in Pair (x,y)`

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to this line:

```
let Pair(a,b) = split_var_val tail in
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

To get rid of the warning, you'd normally use a `match ... with`. If you're sure it's a bug to get something else than a `Pair`, you can use `assert false`, like this:

```
(match split_var_val tail with
 | Pair(a,b) -> ...
 | Nil -> assert false
)
```

`assert false` will raise an exception containing the location of the error in the source code.